# Dúvida sobre o uso de classes "row" e "col" no Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou usando o Bootstrap 4 para meu frontend e fiquei na dúvida se devo colocar sempre todo conteúdo do meu HTML dentro de uma div com classe `col` que por sua vez deve vir dentro de uma uma div com classe `row`.

Por exemplo, deve ser sempre assim:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Todo meu conteúdo deve ficar aqui?</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou assim também é aceitável:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Conteúdo fora da div com classe "col"</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Mais conteúdo...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `row` refere-se a linha e `col` a coluna, é aconselhado utilizar o conteúdo dentro das cols dessa forma que você postou, não todo conteúdo é claro, mas do que você quer que seja exibido naquela coluna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works) restringe conteúdo dentro de `.row`, mas não dentro de `.container`:

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Traduzindo:

> Em um layout de grid, o conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro das colunas e apenas colunas podem ser filhos imediatos de linhas.

Em outro item explica que cada coluna tem `padding` para criar um "vão" (*gutter* em inglês) entre as colunas, e este "vão" é compensado com margens negativas nas `.row`.

Dito isso, as restrições parecem se aplicar apenas a `.row` e `.col`, o `.container` será apenas o elemento que limita o tamanho da sua tela.

Se você ver o [código](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/4b3d2635f34a36742f6f3ab0f969a80b0c21a0ef/scss/mixins/_grid.scss#L5) que cria as regras para o container verá:

```
@mixin make-container($padding-x: $container-padding-x) {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: $padding-x;
  padding-left: $padding-x;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Nenhumas das regras CSS atrapalharia você usar um `<h1>` fora das `.rows`, mas o aconselhável é você usar e testar em diferentes tamanhos de tela para garantir o bom funcionamento.